# Solving the following recurrence equation $T(n) = T(n-2)+n^2$, having $T(0)=1$, $T(1)=5 $

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, computer-science

> Solve the following recurrence equation: $T(n) = T(n-2)+n^2$, having $T(0)=1$, $T(1)=5$.

I need to solve this equation but when I get to the particular solution with $n^2$ some of the terms I need cancel out and it's kind of impossible to find the constants at that point.

Here is the way I'm doing it, using $an^2+bn+c$ to  replace $T(n)$;
$$\begin{split}
0&=an^2+bn+c - a(n-2)^2-b(n-2)-c-n^2\\
&=an^2+bn- a(n-2)^2-b(n-2)+n^2\\
&=an^2+bn- a(n^2-4n+4)-b(n-2)-n^2\\
&=an^2+bn- an^2+4an-4a-bn-2b-n^2\\ &=4an-4a-2b-n^2\\ 
&=n(4a-n)+(-4a+2b)\\
\end{split}$$
But beyond that, I cannot find any way to find the constants.

Comment: It will grow like a cubic polynomial in $n$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula in general.

Comment: If one sets $T(1)=1$ and $T(2)=5$ instead, it solves the issue.

Comment: @JohnOmielan I can see that, but to solve the recurrence I'm not using the values, I mean, if I only want to solve the recurrence, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @leo Based on your later work, it seems your recurrence equation should be $T(n)=T(n-\color{red}{2})+n^2$ instead. Is that correct? Also, as for what you're doing wrong, the sum of squared values become a cubic, so you should try that for $T(n)$ instead of a quadratic.

Comment: @JohnOmielan oh yes, sorry. It is T(n-2), I typed it wrong in the title

Comment: @Leo Why do you think it is a quadratic polynomial? That is where the issue lies. Try a cubic one.

Comment: @Gary well, because the max on the recurrence is n-2, so it will be quadratic.

Comment: No it will not be: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+t%28n%29%3Dt%28n-2%29%2Bn%5E2%2C+t%280%29%3D1%2C+t%281%29%3D5

Comment: There will be two independent sequences for even and odd integers.

Comment: @Leo How familiar are you with solving recurrence relations with particular solutions? Guessing $ an^3 + bn^2 + cn + d $ as a potential particular solution makes sense, and the characteristic equation gives $1^ne + (-1)^nf$. Can you put that together?

Answer (score 2):

Since $n^2=2\binom{n}{2}+\binom{n}{1}$, it follows from the hockey-stick identity that
$$
\begin{split}
\sum_{k=0}^{n}{k^2}&=2\binom{n+1}{3}+\binom{n+1}{2}=\frac{(n+1)n(n-1)}{3}+\frac{(n+1)n}{2}\\
&=\frac{(n+1)n}{6}(2(n-1)+3)=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}.
\end{split}
$$
This identity lets us find the values $T(n)$ separately for even $n$ and for odd $n$.

For even $n$:
$$
\begin{split}
T(2n)&=T(0)+\sum_{k=1}^{n}(2k)^2=1+4\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2=1+\frac{4n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}\\
&=\frac{4n^3+6n^2+2n+3}{3}=\frac{(2n+3)(2n^2+1)}{3}.
\end{split}
$$
For odd $n$:
$$
\begin{split}
T(2n+1)&=T(1)+\sum_{k=1}^{n}(2k+1)^2=5+\sum_{k=1}^{2n+1}k^2-1^2-\sum_{k=1}^{n}(2k)^2=\\
&=4+\frac{(2n+1)(2n+2)(4n+3)}{6}-\frac{4n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}=\\
&=4+\frac{(2n+1)(n+1)}{3}((4n+3)-2n)=4+\frac{(n+1)(2n+1)(2n+3)}{3}\\
&=\frac{4n^3+12n^2+11n+15}{3}=\frac{(2n+5)(2n^2+n+3)}{3}.
\end{split}
$$

Comment: Given your answers, I believe when combining these into a single equation, we find that $T(n)=\frac{1}{6}\left(n^3+3n^2+2n+15-9(-1)^n\right)$. I'm unsure if this is the canonical extension over $\mathbb{C}$ however.

Comment: @Graviton I think that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

**You need to solve for even and odd separately**, but first let's  find the value of the **sum of squares of all nonnegative integers from $0$ to $m$**, a quantity we denote by $S(m)$ and which we will need later.

We make an assumption that $m\to S(m)$ is a polynomial of degree $3$ (which I won't justify here, and you can prove the formula by induction after we find it). Observing that  $S(0)=0$, we have  $S(m) = c_3 m^3 + c_2 m^2+ c_1 m$. Since $S(1)=1,S(2)=5$ and $S(3)=14$, we also have
\begin{align*}  c_3+c_2+c_1 &= 1\\
 8*c_3+4*c_2+2*c_1 &= 5\\ 
27*c_3+9*c_2+3*c_1 &= 14\end{align*}
The solution to this system of equations is $c_3=\frac 16, c_2=\frac 12, c_1=\frac13$. That is

$$S(m) = \frac{m^3+3m^2+2m}{6}= \frac{m(m+1)(m+2)}{6}.$$

Now to the problem:

$$T(2)-T(0)=2^2, T(4)-T(2)=4^2,\dots,T(2m)-T(2m-2)= (2m)^2.$$
Adding up,

$$T(2m)-T(0)= \underset{\mbox{even}}{\underbrace{2^2+ \dots + (2m)^2}}= 2^2(1^2+\dots+m^2) = 4S(m).$$

That is $$T(2m)= T(0)+ \frac{2m(m+1)(m+2)}{3}.$$

Similarly
$$T(3)-T(1)=3^2,\dots, T(2m+1)-T(2m-1)=(2m+1)^2,$$

Therefore

$$T(2m+1)-T(1) = \underset{\mbox{odd}}{\underbrace{3^2+5^2+ \dots + (2m+1)^2}} = S(2m+1) - 1^2- (2^2+\dots + (2m)^2)=S(2m+1)-1 - 4S(m).$$

I'll leave simplifying this last expression to you.

Comment: You don't "have" to solve for even and odd seperately. You could, if you really wanted to avoid the $(-1)^n$ term that pops up.